# Deploy python API on Amazon EC2 Instances

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-requests

I have created a script which is running on a localhost and port:5006 on EC2 instance. I am planning to make it run in the background even after I logout from SSH terminal. The question is that when I try to throw or reach to my script from my  browser or Postman with the following link:

```
http://ec2-52-15-176-255.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5006/main?<myparametes>
```

Steps which I have done is:
1.) Created EC2 Instances of Linux flavor (Which is available in Free tier)
2.) Started the python script in virtualenv folder and listening to the port,
3.) Now trying to reach the IP and the port as mentioned above!

Apart from that, I haven't done anything else!

Please help me with understanding the concepts because there are no such tutorials available which serve straightforwardly

Comment: You should search for one of the countless Python web application tutorials for AWS. There are a whole series of steps you may be missing based on your minimal description. Stack Overflow is best for asking specific code questions/problems you run into. Currently your question is very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that the question is very broad, so starting from a basic step: have you created the proper security group for your instance that allows this 5006 port to be accessible from whichever network you are trying to?

Comment: Yes,  I have for now, allowed every traffic for TCP connections. Do i need to establish a web server to make it run

Comment: Web Server will run on port 80 by default. Your script is running on port 5006. I don't want to send you on a wild goose chase without understanding your script/setup etc but generally speaking, I would suggest logging in to your EC2 instance and run curl commands with localhost:5006 to make sure your script is working locally before accessing it over the network.

Comment: Yes, my script is running locally,I have tried it with POSTMAN, where you send an api request to  the specified url